# Scroll Facebook's main conversation window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to find a way to scroll up a Facebook conversation window through JavaScript (the main page conversation, not the small windows popping up at the bottom of the screen).

I've tried several things, including:

- ScrollUp
- ScrollBy
- `window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight`

And this on different div elements I could find in the page (e.g. "document.getElementsByClassName('uiScrollableAreaWithTopShadow')") but nothing seems to be working.

The reason I'm doing this is to scroll a complete conversation (100k+ messages) with PhantomJS to collect it then parse it, so I can make a giant book out of it, as a gift.

If any of you would know how this is possible, it'd be greatly appreciated, as this is the only thing I'm missing.